# Why can't my jenkins pipeline connect to mysql localhost(windows os)?

Tags: python, mysql, jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that utilizes unit tests in my project. I am using a MySQL database, but I encountered the following error:

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)

I'm unsure how to configure my local host database on windows for this pipeline.

Please, could you help me?

Jenkins file

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'python:3.8.7'
            args '-u root'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Install dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
            }
        }
        stage('Run tests') {
            steps {
                sh 'python -m unittest discover -s tests'
            }
        }
.....
```

db.py file (where the database configurations)

```
class Db:
    def __init__(self):
        # Connect to the MySQL database
        load_dotenv()
        host, user, password, database = os.getenv('HOST'), os.getenv('USER'), os.getenv('PASSWORD'), os.getenv(
            'DATABASE')

        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=database
        )
        lg.info('db connect great success')
        self.cursor = self.mydb.cursor()
```

I tried to modify the my.ini file, restart the server, and build the Jenkins file that only connects to the MySQL server.